# Cloudformation json script about Ec2 instance userdata

Tags: json, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, user-data

I am new to Cloudformation, When i wrote the userdata for ec2 instance in cloudformation. It ran half of the commands but didn't run the docker run. Even it installed the docker but didnt run it. please help me out.

```
"UserData": {"Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["",[
 "#!/bin/bash -ex\n",
"sudo apt update\n", 
"sudo snap install docker\n",
"sudo apt update\n",

Above all command worked. it updated and installed the docker but below command didnt worked.

"sudo docker run -d -it -p 80:80 -e --name demo ubuntu\n",
"sudo docker exec -it demo /bin/bash\n",
"mkdir websites\n",
"cd websites\n",
"npm install express\n",
"npm start\n"]]}}
```

Comment: Did you check the logs to see why it fails?

Comment: I used another command to write the below variables into the Dockerfile. i used echo for putting those command in Dockerfile and then run it.